# Does Objective-C have views?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

The rejection of [a recent edit I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/147693) gave me doubts about something I thought I knew on Objective-C.

I've lived under the assumption that the UIViews are part of iOS, that iOS is a descendant of Objective-C and that Objective-C has no default kits with any views.

I've tried some Google and Stack Overflow searches, but the results didn't seem trustworthy and were mostly about UIViews. [Wikipedia seems to mention nothing about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Interfaces_and_implementations) .

Does Objective-C have views? Or is that, as I assumed before, a common misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem that I see is that iOS is NOT a descendant of Objective C.

iOS is the operating system (like Windows Linux OSX) whilst Objective-C is a programming language albeit one that most iOS and OSX apps are written in. However there are iOS apps written in Python and other languages,

iOS as such does not have views - these are part of the Cocoa-touch framework which is a set of libraries that run on iOS and can be called with Objective C code. Although in practice for the programmer the difference between calling code in iOS and Cocoa touch is not really clear if you are only writing for iOS devices, the split is clearer in OSX where you can write code just using OSX calls or can use Cocoa frameworks.

As noted the views are part of the Cocoa touch framework. This can be called by any language including Objective - C. Most languages do not include the ability to write GUIS as part of itself they usually make use of separate libraries to do this. For example Objective C has no GUI libraries itself but has had Cocoa touch written for iOS, Cocoa and Carbon (although that mainly uses a C binding) for OSX and GNUStep for Windows and Unix like OSes (and historically NeXTStep, OpenStep, Rhapsody, basically earlier versions of Cocoa, on various OSs and Stepstone's ICPak 201)

Comment: Funny, I even knew Objective-C was a language and iOS an operating system, but never realized iOS was not a descendant. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is the open source programming language. UIKit(iOS) and AppKit(Mac OS) are what provide the visual elements - and this is not open source.

Objective-C itself doesn't have a UI, that's provided by other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood obj-c's views are part of the UIKit framework :  [check here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html)

which is designed for constructing GUI applications on the iOS.

I don't think you can use this framework in other obj-c applications but on iOS. Probably there are other frameworks that have views which can be used.

Edit: And yes, good point by @Mark that you are confusing the Operating System with the Programming Language